# вылазит текст из тега p после посадки части сайта на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, css3, html5

Всем привет, у меня вылазит текст когда я сделал блок в котором я делаю пост, на статичной верстке все нормально а вот когда я сделал её на wp получается вот такое 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите исправить пожалуйста

Comment: А какое поведение вы от него ждете?

Comment: В статичной верстке задана ширина 350px, и когда она достигается текст переноситься, а вот когда наложил wp то ему как-то без разницы что ширина 350px , текст не переноситься

Comment: а в инспекторе (f12) если выделить этот тег, что в css?

Comment: На скрине другой тег у вас выделен(

Comment: Нет, там все верно, возможно я действительно не навел на тот тег.В стилях прописано: max-width:350px; width:100%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте правило

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Хорошо, попробую

Comment: Сработало спасибо, правда я не понимаю из-за чего так происходит

Comment: По-умолчанию слово в html не рвется при переносе, переносятся целые слова. В вашем примере одно огромное слово без пробелов, чтобы оно рвалось при переносе и нужно это правило...